# Use value of List<int> inside IN() clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, linq

I have a `List<int>` whose values I want to use inside `IN()` clause in my query.
I have read many similar post but none of them worked for me yet.

Let's say my table **T** is:

```
Id1 (int) | Id2(int)

Query:

Select Id1 
From T
where Id2 in (5,7,9,11)
```

**List:**

```
List<int> ls = new List<int>();

ls.add(5);
ls.add(7);
ls.add(9);
ls.add(11);
```

Now, how to populate this list in my query as no of integers?

**Tried so far:**

1)

string ls = string.Join(",", Id2.ToArray());

```
 string getId1 = "select Id1 from T where Id2 in (@ls)";
  cmd = new SqlCommand(getId1, con);
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ls", ls));
```

**Error:**

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '5,7,9,11' to
>   data type int.

2)

```
 var ls = "("
       + String.Join(",", Id2.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
       + ")";

  string getId1 = "select Id1 from T where Id2 in (@ls)";
  cmd = new SqlCommand(getId1, con);
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ls", ls));
```

**Error:**

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '(5,7,9,11)' to
>   data type int.

Note : I'll prefer the answer without using `LINQ` unless it's only possible with `LINQ`

Comment: You either have to concatenate them in or use multiple parameters.  Or you can use a Table Valued parameter.

Comment: @CodeCaster In my question, IN() is used for an int column which makes it different from the question you suggested as duplicate. Please unmark it as duplicate.

Comment: The type of the column doesn't matter the issue at hand is that `IN` expects multiple values and if you give it just one paramter that's one value.  It does not magically separate comma delimited values for you.

Comment: @juharr Understood. Thank you

Comment: Although if you use Dapper it will handle creating the parameters and replacing your single parameter for you.

Comment: @juharr I am not aware of Dapper. Will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    List<int> ls = new List<int>();
    ls.Add(5);
    ls.Add(7);
    ls.Add(9);
    ls.Add(11);
    string sql = string.Format( "select Id1 from T where Id2 in ({0})", string.Join(",",ls.Select(n=> "@prm"+n).ToArray()));
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
    foreach(int n in ls){
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm"+n, n);
    }
```

Comment: it's not working when the values are string & having white spaces. Any work-around for this case?or any better approach is there?